# How does Ghost Scepter affect sustained damage abilities?

Tags: dota-2

The Ghost Scepter makes you unable to attack or be attacked.  If you use an ability like Exorcism, the Death Prophet ultimate which summons spirits that attack nearby enemies for 30 seconds, and then activate the Ghost Scepter, does the ability continue to do damage as normal?

Comment: Hope Someone answer instead of negative Voting.

Comment: Your question was a little difficult to read before bwarner edited it, so people voted you down. The more effort you put into your question the more likely people will vote you up!

Comment: DP ult, Leshrac ult, etc. still does damage.

Answer (score 5):

The ability is not canceled.

You are unable to attack from the moment you activate the Scepter but whatever you did before continues to work normally.